# Rails - Ask for access code before sign up

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I want to have an additional layer of authentication by asking for an access code from users who plan to sign up.

Basically, users have to input an access code prior to getting into the sign up page. I was thinking it could be something like schoology's way for students to sign up (https://app.schoology.com/register.php?type=student)

I am using Devise for authentication

Comment: OK, so thats what you *want* to do - what have you got so far? What are you stuck on?

Comment: @sevenseacat I've got a sign up page just wondering how to implement a pre-signup authentication

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should not do this: Adding another layer to registration avoid users from register to your site.

But anyway, if you just want to put a general password for the whole website you could use [Http Basic Authentication](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/HttpAuthentication/Basic.html)

Frontend Only solution:
Make a textfield and check the input via javascript. If it matches your code you hide the input field and show the registration form.

With backend:
First put just the password form on the page and in your rails app you need a action in a controller. There you check if the code matches and et a variable like @code_valid = true. In frontend you only display the registration form when the code is valid

```
# /controllers/pre_signup_controller.rb

.
.

def validate_code
    @code_valid = params[:code] == '12345' ? true : false
    if @code_valid
        redirect_to ///where ever your registration page is
    end
end
```